# Cant access magento connect after migrating to a new server

Tags: migration, magento-community, magento-1.3

After migration of a magento 1.3 CE installaion to a new server, whenever Im trying to open magento connect manager, Im getting a page with the following message:

```
Fatal error: Class 'Exception' not found in /home/mysite/public_html/lib/Varien/Exception.php on line 29
```

The error page url looks like this:
http://[MYSITE.COM]/index.php/admin/extensions_local/index/key/[SOMEID]/

The site itself and the admin runs fine.

Comment: Does the file exists, is it readable (chmod 664) and does it actually contain that class?

Comment: @SanderMangel yes and yes - `class Varien_Exception extends Exception
{}`

Comment: hm but its stating it cant find `Exception`. which is weird cause its a default PHP class. are there any modifications to the php settings  that might have caused this?

Comment: @SanderMangel, no modifications afaik. its PHP 5.4.39, and I can extend and use Exception in other php files. Additionally - I dont get an autoloader warning about a missing file for the exception class.

Comment: Ah, I think CE1.3 only supports PHP 5.3. What version of PHP was your old server running?

Comment: @SanderMangel, PHP version on my old server was  5.2.6

Comment: ahhh there you go, that might very well be the issue

Answer (score 1):

Magento CE1.3 is not able to run under PHP 5.4. For that you will need PHP 5.3

Check [this thread on Askubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/116254/how-to-downgrade-from-php-5-4-to-5-3) on how to Downgrade running Ubuntu (and probably Debian too)

Comment: Any reference to this limitation of magento 1.3? AFAIK it had issues running on PHP 5.3 and I have already modified it to make it work. See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1296130/what-changes-do-i-need-to-make-magento-work-with-php-5-3)

Comment: Nope, just something I remember. I had a couple of clients back in the day running old Magento versions that couldnt upgrade the server without updating Magento

Comment: Its running fine, both admin and frontend. The only issue is the connect manager error.